# I still get "Dummy output" for audio after installing alsa-base and pulseaudio

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, 19.04, modprobe

I tried using my audio recently and I noticed that I couldn't any more, I've tried a few of the options I've seen but they do not seem to work:

1. [Dummy Output in Audio; nothing is working (ALSA broken?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/382726/dummy-output-in-audio-nothing-is-working-alsa-broken) This doesn't work, after i run `sudo alsa force-reload`
   I get:

```bsh
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: (none loaded).
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: (none to reload).
```

2. https://askubuntu.com/a/800280/990366 and this too, when i run:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-`uname -r`
```

I get errors that a config is bad:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-`uname -r`
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/8,360 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 182773 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-5.0.0-25-generic_5.0.0-25.26_amd64.deb ...
/etc/kernel/preinst.d/intel-microcode:
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
Unpacking linux-image-5.0.0-25-generic (5.0.0-25.26) over (5.0.0-25.26) ...
Setting up linux-image-5.0.0-25-generic (5.0.0-25.26) ...
I: /vmlinuz.old is now a symlink to boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-25-generic
I: /initrd.img.old is now a symlink to boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-25-generic
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.0.0-25-generic (5.0.0-25.26) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-25-generic
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda8
I: (UUID=b69c28bb-170e-48a4-a279-f4449d689741)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-25-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-25-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-13-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-13-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

and `sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel` gave me:

```bsh
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
modprobe: FATAL: Module snd-hda-intel not found in directory /lib/modules/5.0.0-25-generic
```

I do not really know what these commands do, It's just been trial and error. This is happening on Ubuntu 19.04.

`cat /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` gave me:

```bsh
# autoloader aliases
install sound-slot-0 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-0
install sound-slot-1 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-1
install sound-slot-2 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-2
install sound-slot-3 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-3
install sound-slot-4 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-4
install sound-slot-5 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-5
install sound-slot-6 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-6
install sound-slot-7 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-7

# Cause optional modules to be loaded above generic modules
install snd /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }
#
# Workaround at bug #499695 (reverted in Ubuntu see LP #319505)
install snd-pcm /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }
install snd-mixer /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-mixer $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-mixer-oss ; : ; }
install snd-seq /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-seq $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-oss ; : ; }
#
install snd-rawmidi /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-rawmidi $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; : ; }
# Cause optional modules to be loaded above sound card driver modules
install snd-emu10k1 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-emu10k1 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-emu10k1-synth ; }
install snd-via82xx /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-via82xx $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }

# Load saa7134-alsa instead of saa7134 (which gets dragged in by it anyway)
install saa7134 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install saa7134 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist saa7134-alsa ; : ; }
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
options bt87x index=-2
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options saa7134-alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-usb-caiaq index=-2
options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2
options snd-usb-us122l index=-2
options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2
# Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
snd-hda-intel probe_mask=1
```

`pacmd list-cards` gives me: `0 card(s) available.`

Comment: `cat /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` please edit your question for output.

Comment: @nobody edit made.

Comment: Update the last line to `options snd-hda-intel probe_mask=1`

Comment: do i need to restart after that @MichalPrzybylowicz?

Comment: @Edmund1645 Yes. Just to be sure.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz I have tried that but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Check this for possible answer : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029036/no-sound-after-ubuntu-upgrade-to-16-04

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz It seems that those modules in the solution are not available for my kernel version `5.0.0-25-generic` when i ran `sudo apt-get install linux-restricted-modules-$(uname -r) linux-generic ` 

I got : `E: Unable to locate package linux-restricted-modules-5.0.0-25-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-restricted-modules-5.0.0-25-generic'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-restricted-modules-5.0.0-25-generic'`

Comment: @Edmund1645 Install this `sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-25-generic` package it contains the module `snd-hda-intel`.

Comment: already installed

Answer (score 0):

remove the last line `snd-hda-intel probe_mask=1` or change it to `options snd-hda-intel probe_mask=1` in `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

This ist the right syntax.

If this is your own change, it is better make an own file in /etc/modprobe.d/ with suffix conf.
During an upgrade als-base.conf could be overiten.

1. check with `df -h;df -i`
   you have place and free inodes particularly in /boot if it is a own  patition. if not try `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge`. Take a good look, what will be removed, before you "say" yes.
2. `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-5.0.0-25-generic`
   No error?
3. reboot

If problem persist, show `pacmd list-cards` expand your question for that.

Comment: I have done that and rebooted but I still get the 'Dummy Output'

Comment: Is this option`options snd-hda-intel probe_mask=1` anywhere under /etc/modprobe.d/` active? if so remove it please.  `grep -ir mask /etc/modprobe.d/`

Comment: I have, It still doesn't work after reboot.

Comment: @Edmund1645 expand my answer.

Comment: the problem persists, I added an output on the question.

Comment: My last attempt `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio`  please. Control in Bios/uefi if something is relavant to soundcard.

Comment: `00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [8086:9d71] (rev 21)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [103c:832a]
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus [8086:9d23] (rev 21)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP SMBus [103c:832a]`    That's the output, I've given up, I plan to reinstall everything if  this doesn't work, The sound on the live USB works fine.

Comment: there is no sound module loaded. `dpkg -S snd-hda-intel` please.

Comment: I'd already installed the OS afresh, I have my `/home` directory on a separate partition so I didn't lose data. Thanks for your time.